# How can I make a formula that compares two columns to another two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula that checks the "Shipping List" and compares it to the "Stored Prices" to make sure that the price isn't too high. If the price is high it will flag column C and mark it as red. I know how to do the conditional formatting to make it red but I can't figure out the formula to make this work. Everything I see online only shows a single column compared to another single column.

Please see example spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NvTzjCeYlkvR1o-UavCjW2Zm-GwYxiM_wHdU4qrQWEg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete column C and use this in C3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B3:B="",,
 IF(B3:B>IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, E3:F, 2, 0)), 
 "Price To High", "Good")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Thank you!!! I appreciate it, I have been stuck on this for too long!

Comment: One more question/request. Is it possible to add in column D how much the original item cost if the price it too high?

Comment: use in D3: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C3:C="Price To High", IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A, E3:F, 2, 0)), ))`